# PyScript changing my non-ascii characters after saving

Tags: unicode, ascii, pyscripter

I have this line: `symbols = {"oe":"ö", "SS":"ß", "ae":"ä", "ue":"ü"}`

After saving/exiting and opening again, it now reads `symbols = {"oe":"Г¶", "SS":"Гџ", "ae":"Г¤", "ue":"Гј"}`

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I have the same issue.The line   my_string =  "°"    becomes
my_string =  "Ã‚Â°"    after a save,close,reopen.  Haven't figured out what's causing this yet.

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyscripter/vfvpy8vxKoM
gives the following answer:
" Edition > File format > UTF-8 (no BOM)    (or UTF-8)"

However, even going to Tools > Options > IDE options and changing "encode new files in" from ASCII to UTF8, this doens't seem to have any effect:
 - each time I reopened a saved file, non-ascci characters are replaced by garbage;
 - Edition > File format is back to Ansi

Dom (from France)